# How can I insert this image to fit this action perfectly with keeping the dimensions?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am working on a guideline with Adobe InDesign and once I am ready with it, I wanted to create a 3D mock up using a Photoshop action, but when I tried to insert the image it looks really small. I couldn't fit it perfectly to the action's image. I have used free transform's tool but it didn't work because it's going to lose the real dimensions.

I just attached a screen capture image to show you how it looks like.

[image]

Comment: How do you import your InDesign created cover into Photoshop? Do you export a JPEG from InDesign?

Comment: actually i have download this action to Photoshop and i have export the InDesign document as a JPEG.

Comment: It simply looks like your export dimensions in InDesign are much smaller than the dimensions of your Photoshop file. Could you show us a screenshot of your export settings and tell us the dimension of the PSD?

Answer (score 2):

**Very roughly,** from your screenshot, it looks like you're dealing with a Photoshop document set to 8430 x 6300 pixels (675 x 520 @ 8% zoom). This is about 28 x 21 inches @ 300 dpi ( 6300/300 = 21 etc) or 14 x 21 inches for half a spread. Obviously you can check this easier than I can using "Image>image size"

Your inDesign document should be set to that size. If the jpeg export is downsampling for some reason, you can try exporting your page as PDF which *should* avoid resampling the page to a smaller pixel dimension.

Answer (score 1):

Open your image in photoshop and check the dimensions of it with `ctrl + I` – does it match your document size in InDesign or this PSD template?

If it does, open the template file at the same time and drag your image across to the template file. That way it'll remain the exact same dimension as when you opened it.

Comment: And if it doesn't, should i just resize it? or?